# Why is Time Machine backing up 200GB, when I've only asked it to back up 7GB?

Tags: time-machine

I've excluded most of my hard drive from Time Machine, so that it should only be backing up around 7GB from my home directory:
[image: Estimated size of full backup: 6.76 GB]

But as it's running, Time Machine says it's backing up almost 200GB. Why is that?

[image: Backing up 7.18 GB of 185.45 GB]

Comment: My first guess is that there's more that you haven't excluded (maybe including invisible folders). You can always wait until it finishes, then look at the backup to see what's there.

Comment: I suppose that could be, but then why are those folders not counted in the estimated size that I get when I configure the excludes?